# Spatial Join features of File GDB to shape - problems

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I tried to build a Model in ArcGis 10.1. It should be very simple. At one hand  I have the features of a File Geodatabase as Feature to join on the other I have the target shape. The features from the GDB are Clips from former layers with the target shape.

I am using a Iterator (feature classes), in the hope, that the three columns of each feature class would be spatial joined to the target shape. But Model aborts after it joined the first feature class from the GDB. And even this Join is not correct. Instead of the field values that should be joined, it is always the value "0" represented in the output.

I really tried every option of the Spatial Join Tool, with same or similar unuseful outputs.

Does somebody have an idea?

Here is the model: [image]

Comment: Post your model/diagram perhaps?

Comment: Spatial Join work properly only if the coordinate systems are correct.